# InMobiBanner is not initialized

Tags: android, inmobi

I am getting this error while integrating InMobi Banner ad.

```
InMobiBanner is not initialized. Ignoring InMobiBanner.load()
```

I am using version 7.0.4 of InMobi Ads SDK. I have followed the instructions given in the documentation.

How can I fix this problem? Please help me regarding this.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @EAKTEAM Please check my answer. It works for me.

Comment: thanks it works, maybe a bug in sdk , this is why it now works in XML :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. Somehow, InMobiBanner is not working if the placement id is given in XML layout. So, we have to initialize the InMobiBanner programmatically with the Java code.

**But complete your profile information and add your payment information before integrating the InMobi SDK. Also, don't create any placements before that.**

**Step 1:**

Initialize the InMobiSdk in your Application file with the below code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        InMobiSdk.init(this, "Your Account ID");
        InMobiSdk.setLogLevel(InMobiSdk.LogLevel.DEBUG);
    }

}
```

**Step 2:**

Add the **Application** file in your **Manifest** file and also make the `hardwareAccelerated` attribute of `application` tag to `true`. Check the sample code given below:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    ..

    <activity
        android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

</application
```

**Step 3:**

Add a ViewGroup in your layout so that we can add the InMobiBanner view within that view.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

**Step 4:**

Now add the below Java code in your Activity or Fragment to initialize and load the InMobiBanner ad.

```
InMobiBanner bannerAd = new InMobiBanner(this, 1234567890L);
RelativeLayout adContainer = findViewById(R.id.banner);
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bannerLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (320 * density), (int) (50 * density));
adContainer.addView(bannerAd, bannerLp);
bannerAd.load();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My app is in gujrati language.I have followed this answer.I am getting the empty white banner.Ads not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `InMobiBanner` class instance inside UI Thread as it is not *thread-safe*.

Official documentation says -

**Notes:**

- The InMobiBanner class is not thread-safe. A banner instance must be created on the UI thread.
- Similarly, all methods on this instance must be called on the UI thread. Not doing so will lead to unpredictable behavior and may affect your ability to monetize with InMobi.

Hope this answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to add these line android manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```